# College math competitions ranking

Tags: education

I am searching for math competitions for college students. Of course I am familiar with Putnam, but I am looking for a lower ranking competition. Either US-national or regional (South/Texas). I tried [this list](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/List_of_United_States_high_school_mathematics_competitions) but my first three links were stale. So I thought I ask a live audience. If you have organized such competitions for your students I would like to hear your reviews and rankings. Also, if you have used high school-level competitions for university students I would like to hear your views about that as well.

Comment: Another place to ask may be The Art of Problem Solving ... http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/